# Why thread.stop deprecated and timer.cancel is not?

Tags: java

What is the difference between stopping a java Thread and stopping an instance of Timer ?

Why is timer.cancel thread safe or is it ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Cancelling a timer doesn't have any of the potentially destabilizing behaviour of aborting a thread. From [the docs](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html#cancel%28%29):

> Does not interfere with a currently executing task (if it exists).

In other words, it's not going to try to stop a task which is already running, which could potentially end up with monitors not being released etc. It's just going to avoid running any *more* tasks.

Comment: So if I invoke the Timer.cancel on a running TimerTask, the thread running on this TimerTask will not actually be cancelled, but will keep running ?

Comment: @user470184: It will at least keep running until the current task has completed, yes.

Comment: I see, is setting the Timer refererence to null a safe way to stop running scheduled tasks since they will be garbage collected ?

Comment: @user470184: Absolutely not - the task is running in a thread... why would it be garbage collected?

Comment: Since the timer reference is set to null, therefore unreachable ?

Comment: @user470184: But the thread is running, therefore it's reachable to itself. Threads don't just terminate because nothing's referring to them.

Comment: @Jon, Thread.stop() doesn't cause monitors to not be released, however it can cause updates to be left in a possibly random and inconsistent state. i.e. the ThreadDeath error can happen in places not expected to ever have an error.

Comment: @user470184, Running threads are always members of a ThreadGroup so they always have a reference to them.  Even if they didn't, running threads are the starting point from finding referenced objects, so they are always included.

Answer (score 2):

`Timer.cancel` only cancels timer tasks that have not yet been started. The `Thread.stop` method stops the thread (by throwing an `Error`) and may leave the system in an inconsistent state, since the thread is stopped in an unknown place, possibly while doing something.

Answer (score 2):

Java's `Timer` implementation uses a loop and a flag to indicate whether its underlying `Thread` should continue processing timer events. When you call `cancel()`, the `newTasksMayBeScheduled` flag is set to false, which clears any pending events, and causes the thread's loop to stop (allowing its `run()` method to return). In other words, it does not use the unsafe `Thread#stop()` method.